# Problem with finding a bound on a function for use in the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

We have $g\in L^1$ and that $\lim_{x\to1} g(x)=0$. Let $h_n=nx^n$. Notice since $x\in[0,1]$ for each $n$ $h_n$ is an increasing function on a bounded interval hence it reaches it maximum of $n$ at the end point $x=1$. Notice that $h_n$ is a geometric sequence with ratio of $x$ hence if $x\in[0,1) \lim_{n\to\infty} h_n =0$ and if $x=1$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} n = n a.e. $. This implies that $|nx^n|\leq n$ so we know $|\{nx^ng(x)\}|\leq n|g(x)| \in L^1$ for all $x$. Thus by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we may pass the limit inside. Consider $\int_{[0,1]} \lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n g(x) dx\leq \int_{[0,1]} \lim_{n\to\infty} n g(x) dx=\int_{[0,1)} \lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n g(x) dx$ almost everywhere which is equal to $0$.

I was unsure of the bound that I used for my sequence because the bound depends on n but I have now removed that doubt using the fact that the bound is finite a.e. I still haven't used one of the assumptions, the given limit of $g(x)$ maybe it is not needed.

Comment: It should be $\underset{n \to \infty}{lim}h_n (x) = \infty$

Comment: Yes, for DCT the bound must be independent of $n$.

Comment: You can show that $|h_n|$ is bounded almost everywhere.  This should be enough since you are working with a complete measure space.